# How to move on to the subview in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

Hi i am making a word game something like this:

[image: game image]

My plan is when the user touches on the tiles having letters it should move on to the targets. To achieve this I have made a delegate method called when the user touches on the tiles.

```
func moveTheTile(tile: TileView) {
    print("Moving")

    for taget in targets {

        if taget.isTilePlaced == false {

           let targetCenter = taget.convertPoint(taget.center, toView: nil)
            tile.center = targetCenter
            taget.isTilePlaced = true
            break

        }

    }
}
```

I thought it will work but in reality when i touched on the tile it is just disappearing. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

I have also tried
     let targetCenter = taget.convertPoint(taget.center, toView: tile.superview)

but it is not moving on top of the targets.
[edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI1hz.png)

Comment: You should also add the view. You can not move it like this. As both are in different view hierarchy

Comment: I think this works. let targetCenter = taget.convertPoint(taget.center, toView: tile!.superview)

Comment: I tried to add tiles to targets by target.addSubviews(tile), but it is not attaching them to targets instead it is attaching below the targets.